# How to say 'on the first of December' in German?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to say 'on the first of December we buy a Christmas tree. I know how to say the rest of the phrase but I'm not really sure how to say 'on the first of December' /'December the first.'

Comment: This question seems pretty much a translate request which Google can easily give you an answer. Read [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The best way to ask the question is to give your translation of the whole sentence, and then point out that you are "less sure" of the "on the first of December" than of the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*am ersten Dezember* or *am 1. Dezember* or *am 1.12.*

General structure always is 
[ordinal number] [month name]

> Am ersten Dezember kaufen wir einen Weihnachtsbaum.

Comment: There is an interesting map which shows the different usage of 'Weihnachtsbaum' and 'Christbaum' by region: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f01a/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the preposition »an« plus the date in dative case. The date itself must contain an article, an ordinal number and the name of a month. Optionally you can add the year after the month. But since all names of the 12 months are male, the article in dative case will always be »dem«. This article »dem« merges with the previous preposition »an« to »am« (an + dem = am).

So this are examples for correct usage of dates in sentences:

> Den Weihnachtsbaum kaufen wir **am ersten Dezember**.
>   **Am sechsten Jänner** ist ein gesetzlicher Feiertag. (in the south of German sprachraum)
>   **Am sechsten Januar** ist ein gesetzlicher Feiertag. (other regions)
>   **Am elften August 1999** fand eine Sonnenfinsternis statt, die in ganz Europa sichtbar war.

If the context provides enough information to be clear about the month, you can omit the name of the month. This turns the ordinal number into a noun, so you have to write it with an uppercase first letter. (Exception: If the name of the month explicitely is named somewhere else, then the ordinal number is not a noun and therefore has to be written in all lower case)

> Wir sollten nächste Woche die neuen Bilder bekommen. Weißt du, wann genau das sein wird?
>   Ja, das weiß ich. Die Bilder kommen **am Zwölften**.
>
> Wir feiern unser Jubiläum im **April**. Bitte kommt **am fünften** und bringt ein Geschenk mit.

You can write ordinal numbers up to *twelfth* either as word (as shown above) or as number followed by a dot. The bold marked parts of the previous examples can also be written this way:

> ... **am 1. Dezember**.
>   **Am 6. Jänner** ...
>   **Am 6. Januar** ...
>   **Am 11. August 1999** ...
>   ... Die Bilder kommen **am 12.**  (If the sentence ends with an ordinal number you only write a single dot. There is no second full stop in this case.)
>   ... Bitte kommt **am 5.** und bringt ein Geschenk mit. (The dot at the end of an ordinal number is not a full stop. So the next word hast to be written with lower case first letter, as long as it's not a noun.) (Nouns are always written with uppercase first letter. There is no exception of this rule.)

When used in dates as number of the day within a month it is more common to write it as digits plus dot. In all other cases (not being part of a date) you should write it as a word (but only when it is *twelfth* or less).

If the ordinal number is bigger then twelfth (13<sup>th</sup> or higher), you never write it as a word. In this case digits followed by a dot is the only option:

> Hast du **am 26. Oktober** etwas vor?
>   Speak it this way: »hast du am sechsundzwanzigsten oktober etwas vor«, but don't write it this way.

Also the names of months can be replaced by numbers (January = 1, February = 2, ...). But if you do so, you also have to use ordinal numbers (no cardinal numbers!) which again means: digits followed by a dot. And you *always* write the months number *after* the days number! There is no exception of this rule. So when you see the date »9. 11.« then this is the ninth of November. It never can be "9/11"! "9/11" is in German: »11. 9.« (but the English term "nine eleven" is well known in German, and we know that it means the eleventh of September 2001).

This means, you can write the examples that use a months name from above also this way:

> ... am 1. 12.
>   Am 6. 1. ...
>   Am 6. 1. ... (no longer any difference between the south and other regions)
>   Am 11. 8. 1999 ...
>   ... am 26. 10. ...

You speak (only speak, never write!) this this way:

> ... am ersten zwölften
>   am sechsten ersten ...
>   ...

You often will see, that the space between the ordinal numbers is not written. So you will see this:

> Am 6.1. ...
>   Am 11.8.1999 ...

And also leading zeros are common in certain situations:

> Am 06.01. ...
>   Am 11.08.1999 ...

Theoretically those versions are grammatically wrong, but they are very common in the wild. So get used to it, but better don't use it.

Comment: In den anderen Regionen ist der 6. Januar kein Feiertag... ;)